# How to load a specific page with npm start

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-install, package.json, npm-start

When I run `npm-start` it loads, however it just loads `http://127.0.0.1:8000`.

I would like to load something like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/launch` instead when I run `npm start`

Below is my *package.json*:

```json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.3",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "http-server -p 8000 -c-1 .",
    "start": "npm run serve",
  }
  ...
}
```

Currently it's loading `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

This is what I would like to see; `http://127.0.0.1:8000/launch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Solution:`**
npm install concurrently -g
and then in package.jason file update the serve

```
"serve": "concurrently \"http-server -p 8000 -c-1.\" \"start http://127.0.0.1:8000/launch\""
```